# Trivial graph cut?

Tags: graph-theory

We have a graph $G = (V, E)$. Is it possible to have a cut (S, V-S) that cuts the graph G such that S is empty? That is, a cut that cuts nothing, like the image below shows.
[image]

The reason that I am asking is that I am reading Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition. Here I am studying the proof of safe edges to add in a minimum spanning tree (theorem 23.1 if anyone is wondering). In this proof, it is said that "Let T be a minimum spanning tree that includes A" - does this mean that A is a subset of T and thus may actually be equivalent to B? Or does it mean that A is a proper subset?

The theorem:

> Let G=(V, E) be a connected, undirected graph with a real-valued
>   weight function w defined on E. Let A be a subset of E that is
>   included in some minimum spanning tree for G, let (S, V - S) be any
>   cut of G that respects A, and let (u, v) be a light edge crossing (S,
>   V - S). Then, edge (u, v) is safe for A.

Comment: Since the theorem assumes there is an edge $(u,v)$ crossing $(S,V-S)$, this cut at least has both sides nonempty.